# Checking if python script is run from ArcGIS (arcmap or on server) or a stand alone python script

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-desktop

For debugging purposes I have created a hardcoded conditional that checks it the script is run as stand alone or as an ArcGIS tool. Is there anyway to fugure this out at run time? e.g. some environment variable, global variable, etc.

e.g.

```
dryRun= 1
if dryRun:
    par= 'Hello'
else:
    par= arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
# Do something
```

Answer (score 20):

Check `sys.executable`.

In the Python window:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.2\\bin\\ArcMap.exe'
```

and then in `Python.exe`:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.2\\python.exe'
```

So a simple `if os.path.basename(sys.executable).lower() == 'python.exe'` should do it.

Comment: Thanks, but my main goal was to check between local run vs. server run (i.e. as a geoprocessing service- i think that is the name)

Comment: I believe that `sys.executable` will be something different when run as a server tool as well. Write a test script that issues `arcpy.AddMessage("Executable: " + sys.executable)` to confirm.

Comment: Try to avoid testing for `sys.executable` in this situation. The Python specifications (https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) defines that `sys.executable` is the **path to the Python interpreter or `None`**. `ArcMap.exe` is not an interpreter since you cannot execute Python scripts with `ArcMap.exe script.py`. However, yes, it works but only because Esri seems not to care about specifications and standards. It should return `None`. To be fair, there is an issue with embedded Python environments. QGIS and other tools have that issue too.

Comment: NB. ArcGIS Pro also returns the path to `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGISPro.exe` (itself) and not `None`.

Comment: This is a product of the fact that the system module defaults to `argv[0]` as `sys.executable` and not on the part of any malice or neglect on the part of Esri.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to check to see if you are running a script as a script tool or not.  If it is running as a script tool, you want to set some variables using GetParameterAsText, and if it is running as standalone, you want to use some hard coded variables, is this correct?  If so, you can do the following:

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    #Assign input and output parameters for script tool
    par = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
else:
    # Hard coded parameters for testing
    par = 'Hello'
```

By checking the length of sys.argv you are determining how many parameters are being passed to the script.  There is always at least one parameter (the location of the script itself), so if there is more than one being passed, you can assume that ArcGIS is sending them (unless you happen to be passing arguments from somewhere else).

Comment: well, this kinda works for now b/c I do not pass arguments but is there any more "elegant" way?

Comment: If by elegant, you mean shorter, you can make it a one-liner like so: `par = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 'Hello'`

Comment: by "elegant" i mean something like checking an environment variable, etc. Not "elegant" in python sense. BTW, while I use this structure myself a lot, in the case we are discussing, we are most likely setting many params for the script, so that short-ifs will not be really elegant.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it would be like this:

```
import arcpy
par = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if not par: #If no parameter has been passed, an empty string is returned
  par = 'Hello'
```

Comment: I did not try it before, but I thought it would raise an exception, this is definitely interesting... yet, it will not let me to rewire part of the code logic based on stand alone vs. tool.

Comment: What else do you need to change besides the parameters if the script is ran from outside ArcMap?